# Как сохранить состояние кнопки в RecyclerView, после выхода из Activity?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, button, adapter

Вопрос заключается в следующем : У меня есть список `RecyclerView`, где возле каждого `item` есть кнопка(с картинкой). При нажатии на кнопку, изображение меняется. Мне нужно, чтобы сохранялось состояние кнопки (и сама картинка), если человек нажал на кнопку, и чтобы после выхода из `Activity` и захода обратно , кнопки осталась в том состоянии, в котором она была до выхода. Какие есть пути и варианты решения данного вопроса ?

Вот так я изменяю картинку и состояние кнопки:

Во `ViewHolder` я указал переменную `boolean`, которой указал значение `false`,и потом использовал в `OnBindViewHolder`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textProduct.setText(list.get(position).getProductName());

    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(holder.click==false) {
                MainMenuActivity.basketList.add(list.get(position).getProductName());
                holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);
                holder.click=true;
            }
            else
            {

                holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus);
                holder.click=false;
                MainMenuActivity.basketList.remove(list.get(position).getProductName());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: есть только один путь - записывать текущее состояние во внешнее хранилище (как БД), а при следующем запуске читать из него.

Answer (score 0):

1. Наилучший вариант - как указанно в комментарии - сохранять в БД либо уведомлять об изменении сервер, если список принимается с сервера.
2. Если проект не содержит БД, то можно изменять элементы этого листа и передавать лист между активити, кладя его в Intent, но это не очень хорошее решение, т.к. если оба активити будут уничтожены пользователем - изменения в списке пропадут

Comment: Ответ на первый ответ : Я в своем приложении использую Firebase Realtime Database. У вас есть варианты как это можно сделать ,используя эту базу данных?  Ответ на второй вопрос : передавать можно с помощью putExtra. Но вопрос в следующем : где мне получать значения списка, записывать состояние и передавать ?

Comment: это может помочь https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Firebase_Realtime_Database_List_Data_Tutorial надо либо перезаписывать все данные в методе активити onStop, либо конкретный item при каждом изменении состоянии кнопки и исходя из состояния кнопки - показывать картинку

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но ссылка не рабочая. Мне пишет "В настоящее время на этой странице нет текста. Вы можете искать заголовок этой страницы на других страницах или искать соответствующие журналы , но у вас нет разрешения на создание этой страницы."

Comment: еще раз попробуйте, там прицепилось слово к ссылке

Comment: А вы можете подробней про второй способ рассказать.Какие значения я должен считывать и записывать в список,чтобы потом через putExtra передать в другой активити? Как потом мне перезаписать значения при повторном входе в список? Я просто не сильно понимаю как, т.к. новичок в Android.

Comment: У меня в onBindViewHolder есть значение boolean Click. По умолчанию значение click = false, записано это значение во ViewHolder. Т.е. мне нужно записать в список значения Click каждого item в списке, передать в другое активити, и при обратном заходе в список, передавать список со значениями Click. Я правильно мыслю ? Что вы можете посоветовать ?

Comment: есть список объектов, которые мы передаем между активити, либо в базу данных, либо на сервер, либо в фаербейз. У объекта можно задать поле isClick: Boolean. Это поле мы меняем исходя из того, кликнул пользователь по нему или нет. По этому полю можно устанавливать какую картинку необходимо показать. Это поле будет сохраняться вместе с объектом.

Comment: Так, вот у меня сейчас так и есть. В onBindViewHolder исходя из значения переменной Boolean Click меняется картинка. Теперь мне нужно из onBindViewHolder передать список на предыдущее активити. И потом при заходе обтрано в список, передавать этот список. Так ?

Comment: должен быть еще код list.get(position).setClick(true/false), куда вы установите значение, был ли клик по данному элементу. А при закрытии активити весь этот list можно положить в extra и у вас каждый элемент будет иметь информацию, был ли совершен по нему клик

Comment: т.е. я потом передаю список через putExtra в предыдущее активити, а потом когда я обратно зайду - как мне перезаписать список значениями из Extra ?

Comment: а потом из предыдущего активити передается этот список в это активити так же интентом и нужно еще сделать проверку в адаптере, что если поле false - то одна картинка, иначе - другая

Comment: в onBindViewHolder нельзя использовать putExtra

Comment: туда же передается list, который достается в активити из extra и в активити из адаптера можно достать этот лист, который кладется в extra